# Issue with authentication with a laravel spa, it will not always be logged in and ads incorrect cookies

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

Working on a laravel 8 SPA with Vue and Sanctum. As a newbie with laravel I run into a issue.

I would guess that the issue is with the laravel session cookies as sanctum seems the keep on working but I could be wrong.

**How I reproduce the problem:**

1. When I login it works, sanctum token is generated, CXRF works, laravel auth works and when I
   refresh the page it still keeps working. Still on the admin page.
2. When I hit the logout button it will delete all auth cookies and vuex values and I get redirected to the login page. This looks good
3. I want to login back but at this point it will throw an `POST http://localhost:3000/auth/login 419 (unknown status)`

   3a. To prevent this I refresh the page first, I hit the login button and I am back on the admin page.
4. When I do the tirst 3 steps there's a chance that the authencation stops working and I will be redirected to the login page when I refresh the page.

What I have seen is that I have 4 cookies present when all is working propper.

1. appname_session (this the session?)
2. CXRF_token
3. io (not sure what this does)
4. random value

But I have seen is that it will add a 5th(or sometimes even more) cookie with a session value and this will lead to a logout and a invalid session(laravel side)

I have 4 routes, (web & api not in use for now)

*If I need to post any files here let me know as I dont know what I need to post here*

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
       // 'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
       // 'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    
    'auth' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

**routes/auth.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {    
    Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

**loginController.php**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        //validation rules
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->validator($request->all())->fails()) {
            $errors = $this->validator($request->all())->errors()->getMessages();            
            $clientErrors = [];

            foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                $clientErrors[$key] = $value[0];
            }

            return $this->sendError( 'Validation error', $clientErrors, 201);
        } else {

            $credentials = [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ];

            if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {

                $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

                $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;
               
                $response = [
                        // data
                ];

                return $this->sendResponse( 'Login successfully', $response, 200);
            } else {
                $msg = 'Invalid login';   
                $clientErrors = [
                    // errors
                ];                  
            }

            return $this->sendError( $msg, $clientErrors, 201);     
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if (!empty($request->user())) {
            AuthController::removeToken($request);
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            $request->session()->regenerateToken();
           // Session::flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you refreshing the CSRF token before submitting the login request or after you've logged out?

Comment: That I don't know to be honest

Comment: When I check the values in the cookie they are everytime different so it wont be the same value when I logout

Comment: Are you hitting the `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` in your JS e.g. `axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(...)`, after you've logged out? If not, I would suggest doing so either in your Login component and/or after the user has been logged out.

Comment: No I only call this with axios when I login.